# Wordpress - Loop through images in media library where caption contains text 'carousel'

Tags: php, wordpress

Pretty new to Wordpress, what I'd like to do is create a loop in PHP which gets images uploaded to the media library via the admin interface.

I need to only show the images where the caption text, a field completed during upload, contains the text carousel. I'd like to get the image SRC and Description.

Is this possible?

Comment: May I suggest: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since there is now way (that I know of at least) to make `WP_Query` or `get_posts` to filter out posts based on their `post_excerpt` value, which is where the caption is stored, you will have to add a filter to modify the SQL query created by WordPress.

This should ge you pretty far:

```
// Our filter function
function my_filter($where) {

    $where .= " AND post_excerpt = 'carousel'";

    return $where;
}

// Add the filter
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'my_filter' );

// get the posts (i.e. your images)
$images = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'suppress_filters' => false,
));

// Remove the filter once we're done
remove_filter( 'posts_where' , 'my_filter' );

// Loop through images
foreach ($images as  $image) {
    $img_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID);

    $src = $img_data[0];
    $description = $image->post_content;
}
```

Comment: The `suppress_filters` key needs to be set to `false` when using `get_posts`. It is safe to remove if you decide to use `WP_Query` instead.